# How do I use AJAX to make my login and register page the same in Rails 3?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what the Rails code looks like:

```
<div id="sign_in">

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :f_name, :value => "First Name", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :l_name, :value => "Last Name", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email, :value => "Email Address", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :username, :value => "Username", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, :value => "Password", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :value => "Password", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />

    <div id="login_buttons">
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", :id => "login", :value => "Log In", :class => "curved" %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", :id => "register", :value => "Register", :class => "curved" %>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is what the implementation is like: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/AdQfB/11/

What I would like to happen is, when they click on 'Login' or 'Register' anywhere on the site...it takes them to one page that has two states.

So for instance, it would go to myapp.com/signin#login or myapp.com/signin#register or something of that nature. It doesn't have to be EXACTLY that, but you get the idea. That way, I can hotlink directly to myapp.com/signin#register and they would see the registration form first - rather than the login form & vice versa.

Also, when they are on that page, and they click 'Login' - if the other fields are not available, they are then logged in. However, if they click 'Register' and the other fields appear, they fill out the info and then they are successfully registered when they click 'Submit'.

How do I achieve this?

Edit 1: Anyone have any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if jQuery has a built-in function for it, but with simple JS (you can mix jQuery and JS):

```
window.location.hash
```

will return everything after the hash (#).

In you're login controller, you could do something like:

```
$(function(){});
switch(window.location.hash){
  case 'login':
    show_login_form();
    break;
  case 'register':
    show_register_form();
    break;
}
```

Comment: How do I set the hash though? For instance, say I want when the login button is pressed to load `show_login_form()`, but I also want to add '#login' to the URL. How do I do that? There a native way to do it with jQuery or do I have to have a plugin?

Comment: Thank you for this response. This didn't exactly work for me though. I had to use `if(window.location.hash == '#login') {show_login_form();}` for it work for me. But your response got me looking down that path.

Comment: re adding #login, make the href attr on ur a tag href="#login"